# Docker service not starting on new WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im trying to start docker in the brand new WSL2 with the following command :

```bsh
sudo service docker start
```

then:

```bsh
sudo service docker status
```

result :
`* Docker is running`

BUT on running the test container with :

```bsh
sudo docker run hello-world
```

Error:`docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.`

and the status now is 
`* Docker is not running`

....
**HERE's an example im trying to** 
[**emulate**](https://subhankarsarkar.com/wsl2-for-containerised-dot-net-core-development-using-docker/)

MY ENVIRONMENT :

WINDOWS : WINDOWS 10 HOME,
VERSION : 1903,
OS build : 18362.239

DOCKER :
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

i HAVE downloaded docker for ubuntu according to the :[official website](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

In windows features i have WSL, Windows Hypervisor Platform, Virtual Machine Platform enabled here's a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I dont have Hyper-V

I have been using WSL for general purpose proggraming for about 6 months now. Never got stuck this way

How can I run docker natively as promised by the latest WSL2??

Here's another screenshot

[image: terminal]

Comment: Warning Not everything works in WSL.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor can you look at the example I've included

Comment: There are hundreds of issue with docker. Here is the popular one https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4165. tl;dr, wait and watch.

Comment: Biswaprio I just wanna know whether it's possible or not. Everyone on the internet is rejoicing the dicker with WSL2

Comment: The sysVinit script works but not every networking aspects. systemd way requires heavy customization. In my opinion, WSL2 isn't a game changing thing, it's just a mixture of VM, container tech and some MS juice.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 v2004, WSL 2 enabled, DD 2.3.0.3, all WSL 2 + Integration options enabled. I've reinstalled DD, rebooted and thought there was little left to do but blast my distro and try rebuilding it. THEN I found this post and apparently the missing step I needed was only `sudo service docker start` ***sigh***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I originally asked this question Docker for Wsl was implemented with Hyper-V & LinuxKit by the docker team. I didn't work for me because I had Windows 10 **Home** .

Now that the WSL 2 has been stably released, the answer to how to use docker on WSL is available on the Official Microsoft Docs:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers

Answer (score 2):

The error you are mentioning is present in WSL1.

Please cross check that your WSL2 is setup properly? It needs Windows 10 build 18917 or later.

If you Setup your WSL2 properly then you won’t have any issue running Docker on WSL2

Follow this link for WSL2 Setup -

https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/06/install-wsl-2-on-windows-10/

Comment: maybe you are right, but the article says windows 10 pro needed since wsl2 uses Hyper-V which is only available in windows better than windows Home which i currently have